# Ubuntu 14.04.02LTS resolvconf -u creates an invalid line "nameserver Google's" in resolv.conf

Tags: resolvconf

NetworkManager is not installed.

/etc/network/interfaces had a group of lines as follows;

```
######################
# EXTERNAL INTERFACE #
######################

auto eth2
iface eth2 inet static
    address 192.168.1.234
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.1.1
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 # Google's nameservers
```

I thought the comment `#Google's nameservers` was somehow being picked
up by `resolvconf -u` to create the two bad lines at the end of `resolv.conf`.

But after I removed the comment, restarted the networking service and
reran `resolvconf -u`, the same problem happens.  I tried editing `resolv.conf` to make sure it was being updated.

I have run the folloing command from `/etc`;

```
find . -type f -exec grep "Google" {} /dev/null \;
```

In order to search for a file where `resolvconf` might be picking the bad
data up from, but no luck. Any ideas?

Will `resolvconf` pick up information from a physical router?

Answer (score 0):

The `interfaces` file doesn't accept mid-line comments. Change your interface definition to this:

```
auto eth2
iface eth2 inet static
        address 192.168.1.234
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.1.1
        # use Google's name servers
        dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

Unless you've got delayed updates enabled you shouldn't need to run the `resolvconf` program manually at all. Instead, you can `ifdown eth2` and then `ifup eth2`.